# Calling java function from dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app that must be built for Android and iOS platforms.

And I have a .java file with a function that can accept a JSON value, do some processing, and returns another JSON.

Can I call the function in the java/class file from a .dart file by passing an input JSON and receiving an output?
If so, what plugins or packages could be used for that?
Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For platform-specific code [platform channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) will be useful.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. For platform channels to work, should I convert the java code to Android java native and for the iOS platform to specific implementations in Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: Swift and Kotlin are the defaults now, but you should be perfectly fine with Java and Objective C. I’m not sure what you mean by Android Java, but generally yes, the Java version you’ll use have to work with target Android versions.

Comment: If you have an option to convert the Java code in question, I would suggest converting it to Dart 